# Setting nginx reverse proxy to serve from another docker container

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, docker-compose

I have an app in a docker container running at the port number `3000`, exposed to the host (port 3050 mapped to the container's port 3000), and I would like to use this [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) to point urls like `http://localhost/users` to point/proxy to `http://localhost:3050/users`.

I have this block in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
 nginx_service:
   image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
   container_name: nginx_server
   ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
   volumes:
    - ./ssl_certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
```

Below is the container defined in `docker-compose.yml` that runs my app on the port 3000 in the docker container:

```
api:
   build: .
   container_name: api
   environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST= service.myserver.com
    - VIRTUAL_PROTO=https
   volumes:
    - "./API:/host"
   links:
    - Mongo:Mongo
   ports:
    - "3050:3000"
```

After I start up the docker containers, I can open `http://localhost:3050/users` in browser, but not `http://localhost/users`, which gives me a 503 error for **Service Temporarily Unavailable**.

Maybe I am getting the whole idea wrong, could someone help or correct me with nginx reverse proxy?

Comment: You need to add the forwarding rule in nginx config. Have you done that?

Comment: actually it's not because of the forwarding rule. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After doing some search, I was able to pull together a working `docker-compose.yml` that has a working nginx reverse proxy (**image: jwilder/nginx-proxy** in docker hub) to the node.js-based web app I have in a separate container.

The key to making it work is following:

1. set the `VIRTUAL_HOST=port` in the nginx reverse proxy container, this `port` should be the port that my node.js app runs in its container (not the port mapped on the host!)
2. If you want the nginx reverse proxy to be on `https`, you should set up an SSL certificate, but should set `http` (not https) to the environment variable `VIRTUAL_PROTO=http` in the web app container.

**Below is the working docker-compose.yml**:

```
nginx_service:
   image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
   container_name: nginx_server
   ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
   volumes:
    - ./ssl_certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
   environment:
    - VIRTUAL_PORT=3000  # 3050 port on host does not work!


api:
   build: .
   container_name: api
   environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=service.myserver.com
    - VIRTUAL_PROTO=http   # should be http even if you use https to the proxy, because node.js uses http!
   volumes:
    - "./API:/host"
   links:
    - Mongo:Mongo
   ports:
    - "3050:3000"
```

Hope this will help someone landing on this page from a search engine some day!

Comment: To make `http://localhost/users` work, adding `VIRTUAL_PORT=3050` in `environment` of `api` service and removing `environment` block from `nginx_service` should work, you dont need to map port 3000 of your `api` service to host's 3050.